# copy one directory to another in php

Tags: php

```
       <?php
         extract($_REQUEST);
        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
         {
          $get_folder = $_POST['url'];
       $q = mysql_query("insert into test (url) values ('$url')");
        if($q)
        {
        copydir("test",$get_folder);
      function copydir($source,$destination)
       { 
       if(!is_dir($destination))
       {
       $oldumask = umask(0); 
      mkdir($destination, 01777); 
      umask($oldumask);
       }
      $dir_handle = @opendir($source) or die("Unable to open");
     while ($file = readdir($dir_handle)) 
      {
        if($file!="." && $file!=".." && !is_dir("$source/$file")) //if it is file
      copy("$source/$file","$destination/$file");
      if($file!="." && $file!=".." && is_dir("$source/$file")) //if it is folder
      copydir("$source/$file","$destination/$file");
      }
      closedir($dir_handle);
       }
        }
        }
       ?>
```

this is my code ...it shows  Fatal `error: Call to undefined function copydir()`    in        `C:\xampp\htdocs\mywork\creating-folder\1.php` on line 14. But when i copy from     `copydir("test",$get_folder);` to  `closedir($dir_handle);` in separate file it works   perfectly but instead of $get_folder need to give some static name

Answer (score 2):

Use [copy()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php).

Note that this function does support directories out of the box. A function from one of the comments on the linked documentation page might help:

```
<?php 
function recurse_copy($src,$dst) { 
    $dir = opendir($src); 
    @mkdir($dst); 
    while(false !== ( $file = readdir($dir)) ) { 
        if (( $file != '.' ) && ( $file != '..' )) { 
            if ( is_dir($src . '/' . $file) ) { 
                recurse_copy($src . '/' . $file,$dst . '/' . $file); 
            } 
            else { 
                copy($src . '/' . $file,$dst . '/' . $file); 
            } 
        } 
    } 
    closedir($dir); 
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  // Will copy foo/test.php to bar/test.php
  // overwritting it if necessary
  copy('foo/test.php', 'bar/test.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
foo();

function foo() { ... }
```

This won't:

```
if (...) {

    foo();

    function foo() { ... }

}
```

This will:

```
if (...) {

    function foo() { ... }


    foo();

}
```

In general, you're required to *declare* the function **before** you *call* it. The exception is with plain, globally defined functions as in the first example; those are being handled right in the parsing step before execution. Since your function declaration is inside an `if` statement and thereby conditional, the `if` condition and thereby the whole code need to be evaluated first. And while the code is being evaluated, you're trying to call a function which hasn't been declared yet.

Comment: Thanks deceze but this time the error is not showing but that code inside the function not working seems to be after the if condition it s not coming inside thefunction at all